# You don't have permission to access /phpmyadmin/ on this server. To access another pc localhost in windows 7

Tags: apache, wampserver

I am trying to access another PC Localhost on my PC in same LAN using IP address of that PC, and I am use WAMP Server to connect phpmyadmin of another pc.

I am successfully connected to WAMP server(e.g URL http://192.168.1.8/), but if I try to click on phpmyadmin(http://192.168.1.8/phpmyadmin/) then following network error occurred.

> Forbidden
>   You don't have permission to access /phpmyadmin/ on this server.
>   Apache/2.4.9 (Win32) PHP/5.5.12 Server at 192.168.1.8 Port 80"

Please note that I trying to access another PC Localhost not my PC Localhost.

I am tried each and every thing to solve this problem can not solve that problem.

I change `httpd.conf` file according to required changes

i.e `Require local` to `Require all granted`.

I also change in `phpmyadmin.conf` file

i.e `Deny from all` to `Require all granted`

but not improve the problem

Please tell me the solution of that problem.

Answer (score 2):

`phpMyAdmin` is secured in its `Alias` definition in WAMPServer by default, to protect the beginner from accidentally giving access to things without understanding the consequences.

So to allow another PC on your internal network to access `phpMyAdmin` on the server PC you will need to edit  `\wamp\alias\phpmyadmin.conf`

It should look something like this :

```
Alias /phpmyadmin "c:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin4.6.0/"

<Directory "c:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin4.6.0/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
  AllowOverride all
  <ifDefine APACHE24>
        Require local
    </ifDefine>
    <ifDefine !APACHE24>
        Order Deny,Allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from localhost ::1 127.0.0.1
    </ifDefine>

# To import big file you can increase values
  php_admin_value upload_max_filesize 128M
  php_admin_value post_max_size 128M
  php_admin_value max_execution_time 360
  php_admin_value max_input_time 360
</Directory>
```

Amend it to this to allow access

```
Alias /phpmyadmin "c:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin4.6.0/"

<Directory "c:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin4.6.0/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
  AllowOverride all
  <ifDefine APACHE24>
        Require local
        Require ip 192.168.1                   <-- New Line
    </ifDefine>
    <ifDefine !APACHE24>
        Order Deny,Allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from localhost ::1 127.0.0.1
        Allow from 192.168.1                    <-- New Line
    </ifDefine>

# To import big file you can increase values
  php_admin_value upload_max_filesize 128M
  php_admin_value post_max_size 128M
  php_admin_value max_execution_time 360
  php_admin_value max_input_time 360
</Directory>
```

If you are using Apache 2.4.x you only need the first new line

If you are using Apache 2.2.x you only need the second new line

> **NOTE:** Never use `Require all granted` or `Allow from all` unless that is actually what you intend to do i.e. give access to anyone in the universe!

Comment: Thank you so much to solved my problem, your solution is work successfully for my problem.